# generating checkboxes for a specific key in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, multidimensional-array

I have 2 multidimensional arrays `$investmentProgramExistingCriteriaoutput` and `$criteria` which when printed (print_r) produces the following output:

**Array $investmentProgramExistingCriteriaoutput:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 1
        [key2] => 4
        [criteriaID] => 25
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 2
        [key2] => 4
        [criteriaID] => 26
    )

)
```

**Array $criteria output:**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [criteriaID] => 27
        [key3] => 1
        [key4] => Some value
        [key5] => Yes
        [key6] => 3
        [key7] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [criteriaID] => 25
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => Some other value
        [key5] => 1, 2, 3
        [key6] => 1
        [key7] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [criteriaID] => 26
        [key3] => 1
        [key4] => Some different value
        [key5] => Ναί
        [key6] => 1
        [key7] => 1
    )

)
```

I am trying to generate check boxes for each item in `$criteria` array. However, if the `criteriaID` in the `$criteria` array exists in the `$investmentProgramExistingCriteriaoutput` array, the checkbox should be checked, if not, it should be unchecked.

I am trying to do that with the following code:

```
foreach ($criteria as $val) {
    foreach ($investmentProgramExistingCriteria as $existingcriteria) {
        if($val['criteriaID'] == $existingcriteria['criteriaID']) {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='criteria[]' value=".$val['criteriaID']." style='margin-bottom:20px;float:left;' checked='checked' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo "<span style='line-height:20px;'>".$val['criteriaDescription'] ."</span><br /><br />";  
        } else {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='criteria[]' value=".$val['criteriaID']." style='margin-bottom:20px;float:left;' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo "<span style='line-height:20px;'>".$val['criteriaDescription'] ."</span><br /><br />";   
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see from the above array values, I should get 3 checkboxes, from which 2 should be checked.
However this code print 6 checkboxes instead of 3,

2 of the 6 printed checkboxes them are checked (correctly). How can I get rid of duplicate checkboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than nested loops you might try iterating through the first array ( renamed here for brevity ) and assigning `criteriaID` into a new array. Then iterate through the `criteria` array and see if the value exists.

```
$ipec=array(
    array('k1'=>1,'k2'=>4,'criteriaID'=>25),
    array('k1'=>2,'k2'=>4,'criteriaID'=>26)
);
$criteria=array(
    array('criteriaID'=>27,'k3'=>1,'k4'=>4),
    array('criteriaID'=>25,'k3'=>1,'k4'=>4),
    array('criteriaID'=>26,'k3'=>1,'k4'=>4)
);

$cids=array();
foreach($ipec as $a)$cids[]=$a['criteriaID'];


foreach($criteria as $a){
    $c=$a['criteriaID'];
    $checked = in_array( $c, $cids ) ? 'checked=true' : '';

    /* There is no key "criteriaDescription" in the quoted arrays */
    echo "
        <input type='checkbox' name='criteria[]' value='{$c}' style='margin-bottom:20px;float:left;' {$checked} />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span style='line-height:20px;'>{$val['criteriaDescription']}</span>
        <br />
        <br />";
}
```

Comment: I just needed to replace the $val with $a, and worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: oops, didn't notice that when I posted - lad it's all ticketyboo now!

Answer (score 1):

You are of course getting both conditions in your inner loop as you process through the array

Instead build an array from `$investmentProgramExistingCriteria` containing just the field you are interested in, and use `in_array()` to do the test just once per outter loop

```
$existingcriteria = array_column($investmentProgramExistingCriteria, 'criteriaID');

foreach ($criteria as $val) {

    if ( in_array($val['criteriaID'], $existingcriteria ) {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='criteria[]' value=".$val['criteriaID']." style='margin-bottom:20px;float:left;' checked='checked' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        echo "<span style='line-height:20px;'>".$val['criteriaDescription'] ."</span><br /><br />";  
    } else {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='criteria[]' value=".$val['criteriaID']." style='margin-bottom:20px;float:left;' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        echo "<span style='line-height:20px;'>".$val['criteriaDescription'] ."</span><br /><br />";     
    }
}
```